# XSLT3.0 | JSON-XML || JSON Array conversion

Tags: java, xslt-3.0

I'm trying to convert json to xml using xslt 3.0 (Saxon-HE v11.4 library) in Java.

I need help to convert the Array in Json to xml. Current xslt ignoring the Json Array tags and picking only key-value pair.

Below are the required Details

Xslt file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fn" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
        indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="jsonText" />

    <xsl:template name="init">
        <soap:Envelope
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <soap:Body>
                <DataSet xmlns="">
                    <xsl:apply-templates
                        select="json-to-xml($jsonText)" />
                </DataSet>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <Id>{fn:string[@key = 'id']}</Id>
        <department>{fn:string[@key = 'department']}</department>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="fn:array[@key = 'Details']">
        <Name>{fn:string[@key = 'Name']}</Name>
        <Address>{fn:string[@key = 'Address']}</Address>
        <Pin>{fn:string[@key = 'Pin']}</Pin>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input Json

```
{
    "Details": [
        {
            "Name": "name1",
            "Address": "Sample Address1",
            "Pin": "768"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Name2",
            "Address": "Sample Address1",
            "Pin": "7681"
        }
    ],
    "id": "2503",
    "department": "ABC"
}
```

Need Output in below format

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <DataSet>
            <Details>
                <Name>name1</Name>
                <Address>Sample Address1</Address>
                <Pin>768</Pin>
            </Details>
            <Details>
                <Name>Name2</Name>
                <Address>Sample Address1</Address>
                <Pin>7681</Pin>
            </Details>
            <id>2503</id>
            <department>ABC</department>
        </DataSet>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try along the following lines:

```
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
       <soap:Envelope
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <soap:Body>
                <DataSet xmlns="">
                    <xsl:apply-templates
                        select="json-to-xml($jsonText)/node()" />
                </DataSet>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="fn:array[@key = 'Details']">
    <xsl:iterate select="*">
      <Details>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </Details>
    </xsl:iterate>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="fn:string[@key]">
    <xsl:element name="{@key}">{.}</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Declare `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"` in the XSLT but I think already have, you also need `expand-text="yes"`.